# upgrade from Angular 13.3.5 to 14.0.3 :now sass Can't find stylesheet to import

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material, themes

We just upgrade our application that is using 'sass' to generate our themes, upgrading was done without issues but suddenly we have an strange issue throwing an exception from the Angular Libraries when we try to generate the new files.

```
> sass ./theming/themes/:./src/assets/themes/

Error: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
1 │ @use '@angular/cdk';
  │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  node_modules\@angular\material\core\style\_menu-common.scss 1:1  @forward
  node_modules\@angular\material\_index.scss 33:1                  @use
  theming\themes\dark.scss 1:1                                     root stylesheet
```

I checked how angular was defining these files previously and the `@use` was very different in v13.x using a relative path `@use '../../../cdk/a11y';` instead to the new one in v14.x `@use '@angular/cdk';`

I thought that maybe we need to include any path as a command to the 'sass' executable in order to find the global dependencies.
I included on angular.json the following parameters without success (and I dounbt that sass will use this config file anyway)

```
 "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
     "includePaths": [
         "node_modules/"
     ]
 },
```

Any idea?
Many thanks in advance
Antonio

Comment: Did you upgrade material version also to v14?

Comment: Yes, I did all the @angular/* to v14.0.3

Comment: `--load_path=node_modules` is doing the work.

Comment: Ran into this issue upgrading from angular material 14 > 15 @antonio.castellon comment helped me. Here is what worked for me to compile my sass file. `sass .\projects\cg\src\app\cg.scss .\projects\cg\src\app\cg.css --load-path="node_modules"`

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 13 app (after upgrading from Angular 12) i specified "stylePreprocessorOptions" in angular.json (projects->->architect->build->options) to fix error "Can't find stylesheet to import." where import was from node_modules package.

```
    "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
      "includePaths": ["./node_modules"]
    },
```

Answer (score -1):

We do something very similar using grunt-sass with dart-sass and had to add the incluedePaths option. If you are using something external to generate your themes you might to configure it outside angular. The below config worked for us with our setup.

```
const sass = require('sass');
grunt.initConfig({
   sass: {
     options: {
       implementation: sass,
       includePaths: ['node_modules']
  },
  ...
```