# Angular 15: Can't create custom material theme

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material

I've created a brand new project, running Angular 15 on NodeJS 18.14.2. First thing I do is to add the material module as described in the example web page that is generated. I first select a default theme (which works fine) and then want to switch to a custom theme.

I follow the instructions on the official material site, but as soon as I get to the `@use '@angular/material' as mat;`-part, the `scss-to-css` complains that it can't find anything.

```
Error: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
3 │ @use '@angular/material' as mat;
  │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
```

Things I've tried, that also didn't work:

- `@use '@angular/material/index' as mat;`
- `@use '@angular/material/_index.scss' as mat;`
- `@use '//node_modules/@angular/material/' as mat;`, also with file paths

`@use './../node_modules/@angular/material' as mat;` does work, but not completely as it throws errors down the line:

```
Error: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
2 │ @use '@material/button/button' as mdc-button;
  │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  <..>\node_modules\@angular\material\button\_button-theme.scss 2:1               @use
  <..>\node_modules\@angular\material\core\density\private\_all-density.scss 2:1  @forward
  <..>\node_modules\@angular\material\_index.scss 18:1                            @use
  <..>\src\styles.scss 3:1                                                        root stylesheet
```

Editing the `angular.json` to include this path in the `stylePreprocessorOptions` does nothing, neither `//node_modules`, `node_modules/` or the following:

```
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": [
                "./../node_modules"
              ]
            },
```

No matter which version I add, I still have to include the full relative path in the use statement, which probably means that the `stylePreprocessorOptions` are not working.

At this point I am out of ideas how to get this thing working or where the error might be. Any ideas?

Comment: i had the same issue when i updated a project from angular 14 to 15, in 15 are a lot of changes in the material packages. 

Do you have the line `@include mat.core();` at the end of the file where you have the `@use '@angular/material' as mat;? `

Comment: Jup I added that for good measure, but it still doesn't find the file.

Comment: You could also read the stackoverflow here. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72784193/upgrade-from-angular-13-3-5-to-14-0-3-now-sass-cant-find-stylesheet-to-import

Comment: That does work, but I don't see why I should have to call the sass-compiler externally for it to work.. That should work in angular itself.

Comment: Yes i think that `--load_path=node_modules` is not the answer, i don't do that in my project. in my angular.json i had it written without any "/", only `"includePaths": ["node_modules"]`. 
i think that will do it in our case instead of the --load_path.
I can remember when i was fixing the issue i had to delete the npm cache on every try. 
run `npm cache clean --force`.

But i can't actually reproduce the error, if i change the angular.json, i will compiled without an error.